# Do I need mutex for independant operations on seperate parts of a shared object?

Tags: multithreading, mutex

Suppose we have a 100x100 matrix.

We have two threads that both access this matrix by reference (std::ref() in C++).

First thread is assigned rows 1-50, second 51-100. They both start working on their blocks and writing in to them.

There's no communication between the two threads and no chance that one thread will read/write something from the block assigned to the other thread.

In this particular case, it seems that using a mutex is redundant, am I correct?

Comment: No thread synchronization like mutex needed here, this is an ideal case for parallel processing via data partition, where each thread touch different part of memory, hence there's no scope of race condition or corruption

Comment: Do you need to explicitly use threads for something like this? Have you looked into OpenMP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. If your do not share any data, there is no need for locking.

But you are having this matrix for a reason, you probably want to share it later. To do this you will need to enstablish some communication between threads probably using mutex and condition variable.

In math most of the time threads are used to offload some computations to other CPUs so that their results could be merged later. Merging is the part when synchronization is needed.